# Spring Application Startup

Tags: spring

I'm building a a basic MVC application and I've used all the config files properly. But Still the application doesn't stat. These are the following config files,

Web.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Context Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.com/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers">
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

but I'm getting the error as

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'.
```

I'm using glassfish as my container.

Comment: You can remove `<context:annotation-config />`.As you have added `<context:component-scan>` which do the same thing ie. enabling annotation plus it also scans the given package to find out beans.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, Event after removing the annotation config> I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your schema to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers">
</context:component-scan>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'. as error

Comment: Have you closed the bean tag?? Check the updated schema.Is that how it is?

Comment: There wasn't syntactic errors except the schema location. Actually the error was because the cache in the glassfish server has not been cleared, and when all the resources are cleared and new deployment was made it was working fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get those schema versions from.

change

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.com/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
```

to

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.com/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: I'm using the spring 3.2 jars even then should I use the 3.1 xsd?

Comment: yes unless they've published the 3.2 schemas (doesnt look like they have)

Answer (score 2):

It I don't believe it is `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.com/schema/context"` it is `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`.

ORG, not COM.

I hope this helps! :)